# How do I capture RPi’s hdmi audio output and stream it to LAN

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, hdmi

I have a RPi that is running videos with omxplayer and outputting to my tv. HDMI video and audio out work just fine, but I would additionally like to stream only the audio to my network (via RTP or other means) so I can connect other devices in different rooms and continue listening -- like a LAN radio broadcast of sorts. I have tried using avconv and ffmpeg but have only been successful in capturing audio before it is sent to the tv (on $DISPLAY=0).

I am currently working on [duplicating the audio and capturing](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA#Recordaudiofromanapplication) it that way but have only come up with silent audio files so far.

I can record audio with avconv / ffmpeg before it gets sent to HDMI out but can't get the duplicated audio to record anything.

I successfully streamed previously saved audio files via RTP, but it was a little too choppy for my liking - audio was dropping every 10-ish seconds. Is this a limitation of the RPi 3B+ hardware? Ideally I would like to stream the HDMI audio with as little delay as possible. It is not necessarily my goal to save the HDMI audio as a large file as I plan to leave the service running for long periods of time.

Also, while following the above link, I am not entirely sure what to put as the device name in asound.conf

```
pcm.output {
    type hw
    card <Your Output Device Name>
```

card 0? or the HDMI device?

Comment: You don't "capture the HDMI audio output". Instead, install Pulseaudio if it isn't installed, make a custom audio "null" audio sink, then choose it as default sink and connect it up both to the HDMI audio sink and a stream sink (Pulseaudio has a few choices, including RTP). There are questions on this site describing how to do this, though probably not with your exact configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Pulseaudio to stream audio over LAN

you would need to install Pulseaudio and:

Pulseaudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) for sound levels and routing audio streams

Pulseaudio Preferences (paprefs) for streaming

Multicast/RTP tab to configure for RTP sender or reciever

Simultaneous Output tab to get audio playing to multiple devices

LAN streaming audio can be delayed by 1 or 2 seconds compared to audio source, so audio is not good if you can hear both unsynchronized audio streams at once when moving between two rooms

Comment: Thank you. Between @dirkt and your comment I was able to get it working properly.. My only issue is a ~ 0.5 second delay in audio which is better than I expected it to be. So now I am working on getting omxplayer's video to be delayed 0500 ms but have audio play normally.. not sure if thats even possible